# How to get key value from NSdictonary - iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, json, nsdictionary

I use an API which provides me data from the web. The data is in JSON format, and is stored in a `NSDictionary`. Like this:

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
dict = [parser objectWithString:jsonArray error:nil];
```

**Ggb** console result for: **po dict**

```
        1262 =             {
            "feed_name" = name1;
            "new_results" = 6;
            "next_update" = "2010-02-16T15:22:11+01:00";
        };
        1993 =             {
            "feed_name" = name2;
            "new_results" = 0;
            "next_update" = "2010-02-16T09:09:00+01:00";
        };
```

How can I access the values "1262" and "1993" and put them in a `NSArray`, for use in a `UITableView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, SBJSON's `objectWithString:error:` method will return one of the folowing depending on what the root object is in the JSON message:

- NSArray
- NSDictionary

So, you shouldn't always assume it'll return you a dictionary unless you know for a fact what will be returned in the JSON.

Secondly, you're allocating a new NSDictionary object, but then assigning the result of the parser to your dict variable, leaking the previously allocated dictionary.
You don't need this line: `dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];`.

Finally, since the returned object *is* a dictionary, you can get al of the objects out of the dictionary like this:

```
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys])
{
    NSDictionary *feed = [dict objectForKey:key];

    //do stuff with feed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! it worked out for me! The memory issue is also gone after your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

```
return [dict allKeys];
```